# proof that rank$(A+B+AB) \le $rank$(A) + $rank$(B)$ when $A,B$ are square matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

I'm trying to figure out how to proof this.
I know how to prove that rank$(A+B+AB) \le $ rank$(A) + \;$ rank$(B)$ but can't see how $AB$ connects to that.

Comment: Surely the range of $A+B+AB$ must be contained in the sum of the ranges of $A,B$?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution** $$\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)=\operatorname{rank}\left( \begin{array}{cc} A & 0 \\
0 & B \end{array} \right)\\
=\operatorname{rank}\left( \begin{array}{cc} A & -AB-B \\
0 & B \end{array} \right)\\
=\operatorname{rank}\left( \begin{array}{cc} AB+A+B & -AB-B \\
 -B& B \end{array} \right)\\
\ge\operatorname{rank}(AB+A+B)
$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\operatorname{rank}(A+B+AB) &\leq \operatorname{rank}(A(B+I)+B)\\
&\leq \operatorname{rank}(A(B+I)) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \qquad \text{triangle inequality of rank}\\ 
&\leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \qquad\qquad\quad\,\, \text{since}\ \operatorname{rank}(XY) \leq \operatorname{rank}(X)
\end{align*}